# Translating PHP fragment code to .net

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

could anybody translate the PHP part of this code into .net?

```
function showonlyone() {
$(‘div[name|="newboxes"]‘).each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr(“id”) == <?=htmlentities($_GET['id']);?>) {
        $(this).show(200);
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide(600);
    }
});
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString['id']);
```

Comment: As a side note, I found this out in about 15 seconds via Google.

Comment: Thanks. How did you query Google?

Comment: "htmlentities .net" and "$_GET .net".